# What types of payment should I include?

Tags: payment

Should I include a possibility of a traditional transfer on the payment page or are Credit/Debit Card and PayPayl options enough?

I wonder because not all users have a PayPayl account (myself included) and not all users even have a credit card that allows for online payments. But then again, I usually come across only the two latter options displayed, hence the question.

Thanks!

Comment: It really depends on who your customer are and to a lesser extent what preference you have.

Comment: I second @SteveJones. This is primarily a business decision rather than UX. Obviously, the best user experience would be to provide all of your target audience's top preferred method are, but that's not really a question we can answer.

Answer (score 3):

**Don't offer transfer unless you want to create additional work/cost for you. Having access to a credit/debit card is generally accepted as a minimum barrier to make purchases on line.**

You usually only see CC and Paypal because workflows exist for making these payment pathways as easy as possible for the vendor. The providers charge a fee for this ease of use, but you just pay your fee and the money shows up in your account.

The rules and regulations for transferring money between accounts, however, are not the same, and vary from region to region. My experience is that payments can take different amounts of time, as can refunds.

Not everyone has Paypal, but Paypal presents a framework for providing the same transfer service you describe, and it's free to get an account.

Stick with the standard CC and Paypal options and if someone really wants to transfer from a bank account, they can sign up for Paypal.

If you're really concerned about this type of customer, you could add messaging to your site: If you need to transfer from a bank account, sign up for a free Paypal account".

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure but I recently came across the Payment Request API thing https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/payments/. It says "The Payment Request API is designed to be vendor-agnostic, meaning it does not require use of a particular payment system."

Another helpful link https://medium.com/dev-channel/how-payment-methods-work-in-the-payment-request-api-54b8f2ee03c5.